# Rendering <select> and <option> in separate components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm not entirely sure how references work when `select` and `option` are used together, but splitting them up into separate React components causes them to not work. How can I get this to work?

Basic example:

```
<select>
    {() => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <option>I do not render</option>
            <option>I not render as well</option>
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
</select>
```

`React.Fragment` is mandatory, because components can only render one entity. I was considering/ playing around with `React.createRef`, but ultimately I don't know how things work under the hood.

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-thompson-s452i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind that is because you are technically just create an arrow function with:

```
() => (
   <React.Fragment>
      <option>I do not render</option>
      <option>I not render as well</option>
   </React.Fragment>
)
```

So below you are calling the defined function as well.

If you change it like the following, it will render the options:

```
<select>
     {
         (() =>
            <React.Fragment>
               <option>I do not render</option>
               <option>I not render as well</option>
            </React.Fragment>
         )()
     }
</select>
```

The second technique is called **IIFE**, as the documentation states:

> An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined.

Read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

**Code sandbox:**

Please find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-bas-p4ik9

I hope that helps!

Comment: Very helpful and learned something new today. Much appreciated

Comment: @Andrew Happy to help!